# How to get data from firebase on MIT App Inventor 2 on another screen

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

Can anyone help me to show my data from firebase on another screen **on MIT App Inventor**?

I want to make something like login and sign up APK.

When I click on  login, then that would show the data of the user like name age phone number and etc, I already make a project bucket on my firebase account
but I can't show that data, anyone can help me, please?

Comment: use screens wisely... Before starting to create another screen, first you should think about is it really necessary? See also [Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html) and SteveJG's post about [advantages/disadvantages](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mitappinventortest/ka-LS7wmWxs/wRbs70x2BgAJ), because in only one screen you also can use vertical arrangements to simulate different screens, just set the arrangements to visible = true/false as needed...

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a cloud database on the web that any can access if they have the right permissions.

What I suggest you do is look into making an app with Angular-CLI https://cli.angular.io/ once you have had a play with that you can do a `firebase deploy` to upload the angular app to your firebase project so anyone with the URL can view the app. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying

After that you should look into AngularFire to that will import data from your firebase database to your angular app. https://angularfirebase.com/

You also mentioned using a login, you would need to use firebase authentication with AngularFire OAuth to get this running. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-firebase-authentication-tutorial-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick login form I threw together. When the Screen loads, it displays a loading dialog and gets the values it needs from firebase. Once it has both the usernames and passwords, the dialog goes away.

When the user presses the create account button, if their username is unique, their username and password are added to the database.

When the user presses login, the app checks if the username exists, and then compares the password that was given to the password that is stored in the database.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There´s a

> open another screen ScreenName: *NewScreen*
>                startValue: *username*

block you can use to pass the username to another screen, once you get there just use call the startValue

Answer (score 0):

`if get(value) = passwords` seems wrong. it should be `if get(tag) = passwords`.